# Conformity to ATS Policy when displaying PDF from file system

Tags: swift

I am attempting to generate a pdf from a HTML file, and then displaying that generated pdf on a webView. However, my implementation throws the conformity issue to ATS policy which really puzzles me. My implementation as such:

```
func export() {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
    
    do {
        let htmlContent = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
        
        if let pdfFileName = exportHTMLContentToPDF(HTMLContent: htmlContent) {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(pdfFileName).appendingPathExtension("pdf")
            
            let vc = WebViewController()
            vc.url = url
            vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}

func exportHTMLContentToPDF(HTMLContent: String) -> String? {
    let printPageRenderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer()
    
    let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HTMLContent)
    printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
    
    if let pdfData = drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: printPageRenderer) {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let pdfFilename = "\(documentsPath)/Exports.pdf"
        pdfData.write(toFile: pdfFilename, atomically: true)
        print(pdfFilename)
        return pdfFilename
    }
    
    return nil
}

//At WebViewController's viewDidLoad
var url: URL?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = url {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

My error message thrown here:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
> load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
> your app's Info.plist file. 2018-09-09 14:17:28.909834+0800
> App[1776:93209] Cannot start load of Task
> <038CF619-0F68-4196-8B76-4E70DFD678A8>.<0> since it does not conform
> to ATS policy 2018-09-09 14:17:28.910996+0800 App[1776:93173]
> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022
> /Users/MyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/29504265-F97B-4145-AA09-7E8AD66C5F99/data/Containers/Data/Application/78C96743-8EFC-4D53-8ABA-D384321D2156/Documents/Exports.pdf
> 2018-09-09 14:17:29.078694+0800 App[1776:93160] Task
> <4F930735-1374-4DF3-A72B-F698A2BEA8BB>.<0> HTTP load failed (error
> code: -999 [1:89])

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Where is the HTTP request coming from? The only URL in the code you posted is a local file URL.

Comment: @rmaddy Precisely, I only pass the local file URL but it picks up a HTTP request.

Comment: @rmaddy ok I manage to find where is the HTTP request coming from. It's inside my HTML file where I was attempting to pull images from Firebase.